# PHP to Excel function is not outputting the way I want

Tags: php, sql, export-to-excel, implode

So, I have an Excel sheet download function that grabs some data from a SQL table:

```
  if( $type == 'artist')
  {
      $filename = "competition_details_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 

      $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT t1.file FROM ral_competition_artist_artwork t1
      LEFT JOIN ral_competition_artist_registered t3 ON t1.artist_id = t3.artist_id
      WHERE t3.competition_id = $competition_id") or die('Query failed!');

      while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))) 
      { 
          if(!$flag) 
          { 
              //echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n"; 
              $flag = true; 
          } 

          array_walk($row, 'cleanData'); 

          echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n"; 

      }
  }
```

This function outputs:

[image: output 1]

My desired output is this:

[image: output 2]

How do I go about getting that to output the way I want? I'm a n00b, I know

Comment: Rather than trying to write your own homebrew script, consider using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Comment: Then also consider the data that you have in $row, and possibly collect a series of rows together into an array based on name before writing that array to your csv file